# Google Apps - IMAP usage auditing

Tags: api, gmail, report, google-apps

Google Apps (Business Edition) - IMAP Active users?

I am trying to determine if there is a way to generate a report of users who are actively using IMAP to access a Google Apps (Business Edition) domain.  Ideally generating a report of anyone who has accessed via IMAP over the past pre-defined time interval (say a week or a month) would be very useful.

I know the Google Apps API allow to query and report on users who have enabled IMAP within their specific email accounts.  **However, this is not helpful** as most of the domain users have this enabled already, and I know that many do not use this method to connect to GApps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/reporting/#sample_xml_request) has an [Accounts Report](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/reporting/#Accounts_Report) with a last_pop_time field. The field is a misnomer as it actually covers last POP or IMAP time. You can use this to determine if a user has accessed POP or IMAP recently.

Answer (score 0):

Check out FreeSpace IMAP Auditor for this functionality - 
http://blog.backupify.com/2013/08/19/introducing-freespace-imap-auditor-monitor-imap-usage-across-your-enterprise-google-apps-domain/